# How to make plane thick with shader in Unity?

Tags: unity, shaders

I use plane as wall, door,... using [Double Sided Shaders](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/shaders/double-sided-shaders-23087). I just want to make my wall, door,... thicker so it doesn't look like paper, I don't need to make it look super realistic. I wonder if I can do that with shader.

Comment: While you could probably accomplish something along these lines with a shader, it's likely to be vastly easier to just render a rectangular prism instead so the thickness is present in the geometry. The extra polygons will very likely be cheaper than the parallax sampling math you'd have to do per pixel otherwise.

Comment: @DMGregory - I don't know which would be better yet, but there is some of my case require plane. I'm thinking about doing something similar snow simulation: https://github.com/TheBeach54/SnowSimulation

Comment: Make sure you include that detail in your question then, so we have a complete understanding of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @DMGregory - The snow simulator is just a guess, I'm not sure if it works for my case yet.